# no funciona opcion "plugins" del administrador de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

uso xubuntu 16.04 y la ultima version de wordpress. la opcion del menu "plugins" cuando hago click en ella me dice el navegador "la conexion ha sido reiniciada", he cambiado los permisos del archivo plugins.php por si era eso, pero sigo con el problema. no he probado todas las opciones del panel de administracion pero las que he usado funcionan. ¿por que se produce el error?

Comment: Has revisado los logs de tu servidor para saber cual es la causa exacta?

Comment: he revisado el log con tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log y me dice child pid 28941 exit signal segmentation fault  (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2 .  este mensaje se repite varias veces.

Comment: Y que errores existen?

Comment: me dice child pid 28941 exit signal segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2 . este mensaje se repite varias veces

Comment: Intenta haciendo lo que se menciona en este post http://unmundolibre.net/2009/04/14/segmentation-fault-en-apache/ para saber lo que esta causando ese problema

Comment: juan he seguido el post he añadido la linea CoreDumpDirectory /tmp he ejecutado otra vez el log y me dice ahora:[Fri Sep 23 15:44:55.721377 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6561] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 23 15:44:56.802223 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12599] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 23 15:44:56.802266 2016] [core:notice] [pid 12599] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Posiblemente es un error del template, intenta deshabilitar la plantilla a una basica que venga con la ultima versión de WP 7.7.2 .